# .htaccess redirect, change GET variables

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect, get

Very simple question. I need to change url like

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?page=[x]
```

where [x] is any number to

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?id=[x]
```

Just to change ?page= to ?id= using .htaccess 301 redirect.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match the `QUERY_STRING` inside a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Capture (\d+) into %1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+) [NC]
# And rewrite (redirect) into id=%1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

The above would only rewrite requests to `index.php`. If you want to rewrite *everything*, instead use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```